# asp.net iterating over controls in form

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, webforms

I am trying to iterate over list of controls to determine which checkboxes are checked or not in an ASP.NET web page. If the checkbox is cheken then its text is to be added
to a list, however; the iteration comes returns an error or no controls of the Checkbox type are found.(There are 10 checkboxes within an AJAX tabcontainer). 
Here is a copy of my code.

```
private void populateServiceList()
    {
        foreach (CheckBox checkbox in this.Form1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {

        if (checkbox.Checked == true)
        {
            this.services.Add(checkbox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT @ 6:07 CST:**

Use this inside your populateServiceList() method:

```
        List<String> temp = new List<string>();

        foreach (Control ctrl in TabContainer1.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.HasControls())
            {
                foreach (Control subctrl in ctrl.Controls)
                {
                    CheckBox TControl = subctrl as CheckBox; 
                    if (TControl != null && TControl.Checked) 
                    {
                        temp.Add(TControl.Text);
                    }                         
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: asp.net, not windows forms. He'll have a hard time finding a System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox anywhere on the page.

Comment: have to take into account that all the controls don't have a text value.

Comment: It didn't seem to identify and checkbox that was checked.

Comment: if you convert using "as" you need to check value isn't null. and you don't have to verify the type again.

CheckBox TControl = subctrl as CheckBox;
if (TControl != null && TControl.Checked) { // do thing here }

Comment: Edited with code example in the SS to use a TabPanel. Worked for me. @ Hery, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you probably have Checkbox not in the root of scanning of the form.

In general we use - recursive functions to scan all elements inside a container.

Answer (score 0):

Consider updating your AJAX tab control to use a [CheckboxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx) control instead.

If that's really not an option, change `this.Form1.Controls` to use the controls collection from the direct parent control for your checkboxes instead of the entire form.

Comment: this.Form1.Controls threw an error. Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox'.

Comment: @MasterP - did you read my answer or just skim it? Nowhere do I recommend removing the .OfType() check